# Connect with parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to get the below working from https://github.com/simplefx-ltd/simplefx-api

```
Request:

{
 "H":"quotessubscribehub",
 "M":"getLastPrices",
 "A":[["BTCUSD","LTCUSD","ETHUSD","TLRY.US","GWPH.US"]],
 "I":0
}
hub - quotessubscribehub
method - getLastPrices
arguments:
0 - list of instruments - ["BTCUSD","LTCUSD","ETHUSD","TLRY.US","GWPH.US"]
```

My first attempt in c# is as follows;

```
 [Command]
    public async void LiveTrades()
    {           
        var trades = new List<String>() { "BTCUSD", "LTCBTC" };

        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://webquotes-v3.simplefx.com/signalr/");
            IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("quotessubscribehub");
            hubConnection.Headers.Add("H", "quotessubscribehub");
            hubConnection.Headers.Add("M", "getLastPrices");
            hubConnection.Headers.Add("A", trades.ToString());
            hubConnection.Headers.Add("I", "0");

        stockTickerHubProxy.On<LiveSymbols>("getLastPrices", stock => TradePrice = stock.R.Data.ToString());
        await hubConnection.Start();        

    }
```

I'm not 100%, but maybe the arguments list is causing me the main problem.
Any help would be gratefully accepted.
Many thanks
Scott

**Edit:
Looks like I have the list of instruments correct now.

```
var trades = new List<String>() { "BTCUSD", "LTCBTC" };
string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(trades);
```

returns
["BTCUSD","LTCBTC"]

Connection seems good, but not returning any items to me. Will keep trying

Answer (score 0):

This solved it.

```
var trades = new List<String>() { "BTCUSD", "LTCBTC" };
await hubConnection.Start();
var returnValue = await stockTickerHubProxy.Invoke<R>("getLastPrices", trades);
```